# Unable to access meta object in routes-VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vuex, vue-router

I am unable to access the neededPermissions array in the routes. I clearly have the array **neededPermissions** in routes but every time I try to access the array, console logs **undefined**.

How can I get the **neededPermissions** array from the **meta object** in routes? Clearly to.meta.neededPermissions prints undefined, which make's it impossible to loop through currentUser.

```
{
    path: "/administration",
    name: "Administration",
    component: PageAdministration,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      neededPermissions: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
  },
}
```

**function to authorize users**

```
  console.log(to.meta.neededPermissions );
if(currentUser!==null && to.meta.neededPermissions !== undefined)
  {
    for(let i = 0;i<currentUser.teams.length;i++){
      const team = currentUser.teams[i]
      const validPermissions = team.permissions.filter((item) => { return to.meta.neededPermissions.includes(item.permissionType); });
      const mappedValidPermissions = validPermissions.map((item) => { return item.permissionType;  });
      if (!to.meta.neededPermissions.every(i=>mappedValidPermissions.includes(i))) {
        isAllowed = false;
        next({ path: "/:notFound(.*)" });   
        break; 
      } 
    } if(isAllowed) next();
}
```

Comment: based on your other question, I see this function is called in router.beforeEach, so **every** route navigation is going to result in `console.log(to.meta.neededPermissions)`, but as far as I can see only one route (/administration) provides `meta.neededPermissions`.  My guess is that you have some other route initially loading trying to call this function which doesn't have the same meta properties provided.

Comment: You are absolutely right. That's why I am using if condition to check the neededPermissions. I would appreciate if you have any other solution for my problem. Thank you.

Comment: you've set up your routes so neededPermissions is only defined for the /administration route.  meaning the if statement will only be true if currentUser exists **and** the current route is /administration.  otherwise `to.meta.neededPermissions` being undefined is expected. are you trying to have the if statement be true for other situations?

Comment: Thank you. I resolved the issue by adding the **else**. But I am not sure how to hide the component using authorizeUser method in store.